# Can we use nand device for swap on embedded system?

Tags: kernel, partition, embedded, swap, out-of-memory

Om my embedded system I want to use swapping . On my system we have Nand device only which I can use as swap . But I am not able to so since mkswap /dev/mtd8 returned error:

```
mkswap /dev/mtd8 
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 268431360 bytes 
mkswap: write error: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Check dmesg nand driver throwing error:
nand: nand_do_write_ops: attempt to write non page aligned data

my nand partion info is :mtd_debug info /dev/mtd8
mtd.type = MTD_NANDFLASH
mtd.flags = MTD_CAP_NANDFLASH
mtd.size = 268435456 (256M)
mtd.erasesize = 131072 (128K)
mtd.writesize = 2048 (2K)
mtd.oobsize = 64 
regions = 0

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `kmod-mtd-rw` and some NAND devices are not block devices per se and are accessible only via `mtd write`. In short I wouldn't do that and instead used ZRAM or/and ZSWAP on top of RAM/tmps.